# How can I subset a reference based on only the first chromosome?

Tags: fasta, reference-genome, picard

I have the GATK FASTA reference for hg19. I would like to subset this based on the first chromosome. Normally what I do is open the FASTA as a text file, and then delete all other chromosomes except chromosome 1.

That's awful.

Picard tools has an [option](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/3.8-0/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_fasta_FastaReferenceMaker.php). But this doesn't appear to subset only by chromosome. How could this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `samtools faidx foo.fa` followed by `samtools faidx foo.fa chr1 > your_subset_file.fa` (or whatever the first chromosome is). The output file is then a regular fasta file subset as you like. You can get any chromosome you want with that. In fact, you can also do regions (e.g., `chr1:100-1000`, though note that the sequence name in the resulting fasta output will be `chr1:100-1000`, which may break some downstream tools).

Comment: 'samtools faidx foo.fa chr1 > your_subset_file.fa' seems problematic for downstream analysis, specifically ipdSummary doesn't work with the resulted fasta file, and it seems the header is not saved correctly.

Comment: Then that's likely a bug in ipdSummary.